# Google Play 64-bit compliance with using Realm in the project

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

In my project, I'm using Realm. I followed all the steps as defined by [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/). To make the app, 64-bit compliant, the [steps](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) mentioned by Google are also followed. 
In my app gradle.build, I added this in the defaultConfig:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86' ,'x86_64'
```

APK analyzer shows all the required `.so` files as expected:
[image]

The APK works fine on the real devices as well as on the Emulators. However, when I submit the APK to Google playstore, I get the error:

[image]

I have already looked at similar questions on StackOverflow but could not find any solution to this. Anybody else using Realm and found the solution to this issue, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Those libraries [are not available at the moment](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/issues/293) and the Google Play team is aware of it. Let's hope they publish an update soon.